# How do we compute the time delay between two similar time series in python?

Tags: python, time-series, signals, cross-correlation, timedelay

I tried using np.correlate and signal.correlate functions to compute the time delay between two time series. But the lag is not corresponding to actual time delay that can be inferred from the graph.

```
    x = 0.4
    # x = 0.25
    # x = 0.1
    # n = 100000
    # n_repeats = 100
    n = 100
    n_repeats = 1

    # Get correlations
    t = np.linspace(0, n_repeats,n)

    sin_delay = lambda delay: np.sin(2.0 * np.pi * (t - delay))

    signal1 = sin_delay(delay=0)
    signal2 = sin_delay(delay=x)

    corr11 = signal.correlate(signal1, signal1, mode='full')
    corr12 = signal.correlate(signal1, signal2, mode='full')

    a1 = np.argmax(corr11)
    a2 = np.argmax(corr12)

    # Print output
    print(a1, a2, x, n_repeats * (a1 - a2) / n)
```

I used the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/64030308/5235490 to test it on time shifted sine waves. But I don't see any similarity in a2 and x values. How do we get the time delay value from signal.correlate?

Comment: I think the answer to your question lies in the answer you linked... Use more "repeats" and a finer sampling (increasing n) for a more accurate estimate. And bear in mind that the delay will be the modulo the period of signal1 and two since they are periodic of the same period. So if you chose a delay of 0.7, you may find an estimated delay of -0.3. You can also find more information about lags in cross-correlation in this answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64128576/5303618

Comment: Cross-Correlation is not suited for short time-series, see Vio and Wamtaker 2001 (https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/317967). I agree with the anwer above.