# Finding where an excerpt starts in an audio file: cross-correlation coefficients between two arrays in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, correlation, cross-correlation

I have been pulling my hair on a problem, and all of the answers I found on StackOverflow so far did not help - so I am asking for your help.

## The overall problem

I would like to create a function that **finds the exact timestamp where an audio excerpt starts in a larger audio file**. For test purposes, I used a 5 minutes audio file and a 43 second excerpt of it. Below, I aligned the two audio files in Audacity: the excerpt starts exactly at 00:01:55.554920.

[image: Exact alignment in Audacity between an audio file and a 43-second excerpt.]

I would also like the function to return a value if, and only if it has a **confidence value** over a certain threshold, that would actually be a parameter of the function. The way I intend to do it is by checking **if the correlation coefficient between the two aligned signals is over the given threshold**.

In other words, here is a simplified version of the code:

```
find_excerpt_starting_sample(original_audio, excerpt, threshold):

    # Find the cross-correlation coefficients for each lag
    xcorr = cross_correlation(original_audio, excerpt)

    # Return the lag of the max correlation if it is over threshold
    if np.max(xcorr) > threshold:
        return np.argmax(xcorr)
    else:
        raise Exception("No correlation over threshold found.")
```

I have been having a lot of troubles finding the right `cross_correlation` function, because none of my attempts returned an array that would be between 0 and 1.

## The problem, simplified

As my attempts on the audio files have been inconclusive, I have tried to perform the same thing on two numerical arrays:

```
y1 = [2, 22, 14, 8, 0, 4, 8, 16, 26, 6, 12, 14, 16, 2, 6]
y2 = [4, 8, 16, 26, 6, 12]
```

Here, y2 contains a subset of y1 (starting at index 5). In order to make sure that the function works independently of the amplitude scale, I halved all of the values of y2:

```
y1 = [2, 22, 14, 8, 0, 4, 8, 16, 26, 6, 12, 14, 16, 2, 6]
y2 = [2, 4, 8, 13, 3, 6]
```

**I would like to create a cross-correlation function that returns an array where the value at lag 5 is 1.**

## My attempts so far

### np.corrcoef

If we just do a simple correlation and slide the excerpt along the original audio, it works:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

corr = np.zeros(len(y1) - len(y2))
for i in range(len(y1) - len(y2)):
    corr[i] = np.corrcoef(y1[i:i+len(y2)], y2)[0][1]

print(corr)
plt.plot(corr)
plt.show()
```

The output is:

```
[ 0.18961375 -0.71250433 -0.56075283 -0.08468414  0.21913077  1. -0.04179451 -0.46803451 -0.24815461]
```

[image: The cross-correlation, using np.corrcoeff]

The problem is that this technique is really, really not efficient for longer files.

### scipy.signal.correlate

Now, instead of reinventing the wheel, I started using one of the main solutions found on Stack Overflow, i.e. the correlate function of scipy.signal. It returns values where the proper lag is found. However, as is, because it performs a convolution, there is no way to quantify the correlation.

```
from scipy import signal

xcorr = signal.correlate(y1, y2, mode="full")
lags = signal.correlation_lags(len(y1), len(y2), mode="full")

print(xcorr)
print(lags)
plt.plot(lags, xcorr)
plt.show()
```

The output is:

```
[ 12 138 176 392 390 332 224 232 356 402 596 486 478 414 422 252 186  88 28  12]
[-5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14]
```

[image: The cross-correlation, using scipy.signal.correlate]

I saw a few solutions, but they do not work as I intend.

First, a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64128576) suggests to normalize the coefficient using this function:

```
corr = signal.correlate(y1 / np.std(y1), y2 / np.std(y2), 'full') / min(len(y1), len(y2))
lags = signal.correlation_lags(len(y1), len(y2), mode="full")
print(c)
plt.plot(lags, c) 
plt.show()
```

The output is:

```
[0.0736392  0.84685082 1.08004163 2.40554727 2.39327407 2.03735126 1.37459844 1.42369124 2.18462966 2.46691327 3.65741371 2.98238769 2.93329489 2.54055247 2.58964528 1.54642325 1.14140763 0.54002082 0.17182481 0.0736392 ]
```

[image: The normalized cross-correlation, using scipy.signal.correlate]

As you can see, the maximum value is not 1, but 3.65741371.

I then tried another solution found [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/41217):

```
y1n = y1 / np.std(y1)
y2n = y2 / np.std(y2)
xcorr = signal.correlate(y1n, y2n, mode="full")
lags = signal.correlation_lags(len(y1), len(y2), mode="full")
print(xcorr)
plt.plot(lags, xcorr)
plt.show()
```

The output is:

```
[ 0.44183521  5.08110495  6.48024979 14.43328362 14.35964442 12.22410756  8.24759064  8.54214745 13.10777798 14.80147963 21.94448224 17.89432612 17.59976931 15.24331484 15.53787165  9.27853947  6.8484458   3.24012489  1.03094883  0.44183521]
```

[image: A second attempt at the normalized cross-correlation, using scipy.signal.correlate]

Once again, the max value for the cross-correlation is not 1 but 21.94448224

## A cry for help

**There is a lot I do not know about correlation - I dug into it, but before going deeper I'm asking, if one of you happened to be able to point me in the right direction, and what I did wrong so far.**

**Thanks a lot!**

Comment: What is the average size of y1 and y2? do you have millions of elements in y1 and y2? or are they relatively big, ie y1 1e5?

Comment: @Onyambu : The elements are very big. Ideally, I would like to be able to find a 1 minute excerpt in a 2 hour recording, so, at 44100 Hz, that translates to about 2e6 samples for the excerpt, and 3e8 samples for the recording. 

That being said, I can downsample the vectors, but I don't know to what extend that will decrease the precision of the cross-correlation.

Note: I do not intend to perform the cross-correlation on the audio clips themselves, but rather on their envelopes, on which I would have applied a 50-Hz low-pass filter.

Comment: So your y1 is 3e8 and y2 is 2e6?

Comment: @Onyambu: exactly, yes

Comment: With 3e8 that is 300 million. Consider using C. Or read in by chunks. A simple statement like just creating a list comprehension for the numbers `import timeit; timeit.timeit('[i for i in range(int(3e8))]', number = 1)`  takes roughly 20 seconds. Thats just to list the numbers. eg `timeit.timeit('list(range(int(3e8)))', number = 1)` also takes 20secs. running a for loop without anything ie `timeit.timeit('for i in range(int(3e8))', number = 1)` will take roughly 7secs. Thats just to count from 1 to 300million without doing anything else. Meaning your code will take a lot of time.

Comment: Note that with the code i gave, you have to go over the 1:300million 3 times ie 3 convolutions. You can prevent this by using some for loops. and if possible avoid using mean, std, cor. Just standardize y2, then you can do value updates for y1. ie think of adding a new value. eg for mean `new_mean = old_mean + (new_value - oldest_value)/y2.size`. With this method, you do not have to compute mean every time but rather just update the previous mean by the above formula. Same with std and thus able to do evertyhing within one for loop

Answer (score 1):

You can use convolution for this:

```
def cross_corr(x, y):
  x = np.array(x)
  y = np.array(y[::-1])
  yi = (y - y.mean())/ y.std() / np.sqrt(y.size)
  x_m = np.convolve(x, np.ones(yi.size), 'valid')**2/yi.size
  x_m2 = np.convolve(x**2, np.ones(yi.size), 'valid')
  return np.convolve(x, yi, 'valid')/np.sqrt(x_m2 - x_m)

cross_corr(y1,y2)
array([ 0.18961375, -0.71250433, -0.56075283, -0.08468414,  0.21913077,
        1.        , -0.04179451, -0.46803451, -0.24815461,  0.77716484])
```

This function is a lot of magnitudes faster to the original solution

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer :)
It looks like it works! I will test it with my audio files, but it looks very promising!

Comment: @Paidon you can optimize the code further by removing two convolutions are also using numba

Comment: I just tried to use your function on the audio clips I describe at the beginning of my problem, and it is still running as I write that comment, despite downsampling the clips to 1000 Hz. I am not sure what you mean by removing two convolutions? Which ones are you mentioning?

Comment: @Paidon `x_m` and `x_m2` can be combined into one simple for loop with updates. No convolution. This will reduce the time taken to compute each by a magnitude of 2

Answer (score 0):

I adapted the code from @Onyambu (thanks again for your help!) in order to replace the convolutions by `signal.correlate()`. Here is what I got:

```
import numpy as np

def cross_correlation(y1, y2):
    y2_normalized = (y2 - y2.mean()) / y2.std() / np.sqrt(y2.size)
    y1_m = signal.correlate(y1, np.ones(y2.size), 'valid') ** 2 / y2_normalized.size
    y1_m2 = signal.correlate(y1 ** 2, np.ones(y2.size), "valid")
    cross_correlation = signal.correlate(y1, y2_normalized, "valid") / np.sqrt(y1_m2 - y1_m)
```

The code is much faster when cross-correlating audio files; the execution of the code took less than 2 seconds for the audio clips I mentioned at the beginning of my problem (that are 5 minutes and 43 seconds, respectively, sampled at 44100 Hz).

Here is the output:
[image: The output of the cross-correlation of two audio files]

The peak has a value of 1.0, and is precise to the millisecond.

Note: before performing the cross-correlation, I got the envelope of both of the audio files using `y_env = np.abs(scipy.signal.hilbert(y))` and a low-pass filter at 50 Hz using `b, a = scipy.signal.butter(2, filter_over, "low", fs=44100)` and `y_filt = lfilter(b, a, y_env)`. You can also perform a downsampling at any point in case you have very long data.